# Using OpenID Connect to share data

Tags: content-management-system, openid, openid-connect

I am an OpenID neophyte, so please correct me if I'm using the wrong terminology, but here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

I have a web site, let's call it "LB" which has a database. I've also created my own OpenID Connect identity server "IDS", and configured LB to use it for logging in. IDS doesn't have its own database, it's using LB's database.

Now, I want to introduce a CMS (like WordPress or Umbraco or whatever) into the mix. I want the CMS to use IDS, so that a single sign-on can be shared between LB and CMS. That seems relatively straightforward to do with a [plugin like this one](https://github.com/jumbojett/Wordpress-OpenID-Connect-Login).

So now, suppose there is some bit of data in LB that I want to integrate with the CMS. Maybe while on the CMS site, the user can go to a profile page or something, and I want to show some interesting bits from LB on that profile page. Could be something dynamic that is affected by the user's activity in LB, maybe a HTML snippet, an image, or just some raw JSON to put into a template. Is the [UserInfo endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) what I should be using for this? (E.g. CMS asks IDS for the info) Or should CMS talk directly to LB somehow (and if so, how)?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit abstract so I may be off, but if you want to return an arbitrary data, then it probably is better to create a new endpoint representing that "protected resource" such as https://LB.example.com/activities. You get an access token with OpenID Connect login, so you can use that to access this oauth protected resource.